# List (find) files with repeated pattern in their name

Tags: regex, linux, find, ls

My question is so simple, but I could not find any solution yet.
I need to find files with the date (string) repeated in their names. For example:

20190101_fl_20190101.nc

20190101_fl_20190104.nc
20190102_fl_20190102.nc
20190102_fl_20190104.nc

I need to find **20190101_fl_20190101.nc and 20190102_fl_20190102.nc**.

I have tried

```
ls 20190[0-9][0-9][0-9]_fl_20190[0-9][0-9][0-9].nc
```

But, as expected, it finds all possible combinations.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/(20190[0-9]{3})_fl_\1\.nc$'
```

The regex matches

- `.*/` - any chars up to the rightmost `/` (necessary because the pattern used with `find` requires a full string match)
- `(20190[0-9]{3})` - Group 1: `2019` and any three digits
- `_fl_`  - a fixed substring
- `\1` - backreference to Group 1 value
- `\.nc` - `.nc` string
- `$` - end of input.

The `-regextype posix-extended` option is necessary since the pattern above is POSIX ERE compliant.